# npm/grunt: is it possible to install grunt without npm?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I am having so much problems with the proxy system of my entertprise

I was changing parameter using npm config set changing the variable proxy and http-proxy.

I installed in my .npmrc next lines

```
npm config set proxy http://my_user:my_password@10.3.12.130:8080 -g
npm config set https-proxy http://my_user:my_password@10.3.12.130:8080 -g
```

What I have in my mind it is try to install grunt in VS2012 without using npm, maybe like nuget.

Is it possible?

I am getting this error page when I am using  `npm install -g grunt-cli`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

This is from the [Grunt getting started guide](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started):

> Grunt and Grunt plugins are installed and managed via npm, the Node.js
>   package manager. Grunt 0.4.x requires stable Node.js versions >=
>   0.8.0. Odd version numbers of Node.js are considered unstable development versions.

Comment: I uploaded you what it happens me when I am trying to execute `npm install -g grunt-cli`. do you have any idea to resolve it the with npm, because I think it is everything ok in my machine

Comment: I got it using a wifi lan which doesnt have proxy. It is curious because VS2012 I creted the node project empty and in installyng new npm packages the list is working with proxy but after installing the concret package crash. Maybe as you mentioned it is a problem of that odd version.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible, you can download grunt and run it in your node.js environment, if your only problem is proxy or firewall but you have working node.js environment then just download it from the [github](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt).

You can download any npm package which is published also on the github and then copy it manually to you `node_modules` folder. Just beware that those packages may have dependencies on their own. SO that means you should run `npm install` in those downloaded folders and if it doesn't work do it manually for every dependency recursively until you are finished.

Comment: yes we can but using npm install always crash. the solution is what I marked.

Comment: you dont have to do `npm install` if you download all grunt dependenices from github too (and put them into grunt's `node_modules`, also recursivelyu for every dependency). ALso faster would be to install it on other machine and then just copy to machine with vblocked npm